# Push Notification using Ejabberd 16/17

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, ejabberd

I want to Send push notification in android and iOS phone using Ejabberd and backend is mysql. I read so many articles but not getting solution for both.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps that you can try to send push notification to mobile user.

1. Mobile endpoint needs to be registered with ejabberd server. It means GCM/APNS token which user receives while registering with those services needs to be passed to server and server will make a entry in DB. So whenever there is event for that particular user, it will send event to stored endpoint in DB.
   For simplicity of implementation , I used AWS SNS service. Which sends notification to both Android and iOS devices. I used [this](https://github.com/erlcloud/erlcloud) library for that.
2. Tap available hooks for raising events. For e.g. you can tap to 'user_send_packet','user_receive_packet','muc_filter_message' etc to your module and trigger GCM/APNS/SNS events as per participants involved in that. You can create your own hook to have more events as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 
[mod_push in ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/pull/1881)
 or this [mod_zeropush](https://github.com/kevb/mod_zeropush)

```
mod_zeropush:
    sound: "default"
    auth_token: "your-auth-token"
    post_url: "https://your-internal-service/notify"
```

This used to call our server API to send PUSH notification.